# Determining behavior of heat exchange system

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I'm trying to develop a thermoelectric (Peltier tile-based) beverage cooling system. Ideally, I'd also like a device to solve the warm beer problem if the thermodynamics give me any confidence.

First, I'll detail my thought flow in the theory sense and then I'll get to my specific setup that I had in mind.

Obviously, if one immerses a 100 W, 10% efficient Peltier tile in a glass of water at 298 K (let's say, containing 10 mol exactly), if the container system is assumed to be adiabatic in nature, to drop the temperature to 274 K (roughly 35 °F) requires:

$$
Q = m \, c_p \, \Delta T = 180.2 \times 4.1813 \times 24 = 18083.3 \:\mathrm{J}
$$

Then, since the efficiency gives the nominal "heat transfer" power to be 10 W:

$$
t = \frac{18083.3\:\mathrm{J}}{10\:\mathrm{J/s}} = 1808.33 \:\mathrm{s}
$$

So, the cooling would take about 30 minutes to chill the glass down, much more when you consider that a glass of water doesn't adhere closely to adiabatic behavior.

The actual setup (poorly-drawn hand sketch follows):

[image: The experimental setup]

Now, obviously there are four sets of values to consider here:

- The specific heat and thermal conductivity of the beverage itself
- The specific heat and thermal conductivity of the glass container holding the beverage, easily *approximated* by making the assumption that the glass can be characterized by fused silica
- The specific heat and thermal conductivity of the water transfer fluid, well-established
- The specific heat and thermal conductivity of the 6061 aluminum working chamber, which is again well-established

My problem is how to model the system and get model calculations for the transfers between each step, so, for example, solving the equation so I know if I use a given cumulative wattage of Peltier tile, it'll reduce the temperature of the system by a given amount in a certain amount of time.

As before, I'm willing to concede, for the purposes of discussion, that this system can be assumed to be adiabatic with respect to the external environment; that is, no heat is absorbed from the environment during the cooling process.

Comment: you are missing how much heat the pelier cooler will radiate on it's hot side, given a tempreature.

Comment: I'm not missing that, I'm just not interested in making that part of the model. Effectively, once heat gets transferred to the Peltier cooler, I don't mind what happens to it as long as it doesn't go backwards. For the sake of discussion, I'm planning on cooling the tiles at potentially a much higher rate than the rate at which they could pull energy from the system.

Comment: FWIW on the cooling side the "figure of merit" will be the K/W (temperature differential per Watt) rating of the heat sink. Even though you do not wish to consider it at present it is a non-trivial part of the real world problem. Heat energy out is about 110 Watt. Delta T desired is 24 K. Every degree K drop across the heatsink comes off the cooling budget for a given external ambient sink. To get 1 degree K delta at the HS you need 0.01 K/W HS which is about undoable. Somewhere in the 0.01 - 0.1   K/W range becomes conceivable but even a 0.1 k/W HS is better than you'd get passively ....

Comment: ... without humungous metal work. So you are into blown air (at east), possibly fluid circulation and  probably heat pipes to get the energy to where the HS can get at it. All this is if you want the HS to effectively be able to be ignored. Mere mortals usually accept a more significant delta T and factor it into the requirement. | A starting point for modelling, which is liable to be "not too bad" is to model each portion of the thermal path as an equivalent thermal resistance with Rth proportional to k.t/A (t = thickness of material, A = area , k = constant based on material. I suspect ....

Comment: ....the Al bucket will have negligible effect,  the glass not as bad as you might expect as long as as thin as would be sensible, and water non-homogeneity is probably more important than thermal resistance - ie if you really are providing semi infinte cooling then stirring the water probably makes sense. | Finger in air feel suggests a few degrees (say 1 to 10 depending on stage of cooling) differential between water and target fluid. | Something I've not seen done - but I assume it is, is to use heap pipes to get the Peltier coolth to where it belongs. If you are allowed to open the ....

Comment: .... target container (beer drinkers will protest) then a heat pipe based cold finger would get coolth into the middle of the beverage. Heat pipes can be MUCH simpler than may be apparent. Add a calculated amount of eg water to a strong enough evacuatable container, suck out desired air % and seal it and you have a potential heat pipe. Getting the condensed fluid 'back home' and providing suitable energy in/out interfaces adds to the fun but the hardest part has been done. Or you can buy them at almost reasonable rates. | If you were really serious about cooling applications like this ....

Comment: .... then a Stirling cooler based one is vastly superior except in areas of difficulty and cost :-) :-(. Stirling fun factor is 'right up there'. For some real world examples look at the 'badge engineered' Coleman Stirling based portable coolers from some years back. I do not know if these are still available. Cost was nasty, efficiency in real cooling per Watt was probably an order of magnitude plus better than Peltier. || Peltier have a falloff of throughput with delta T and an upper Tdifferntial they can be used at. Probably not an issue in your application.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Well, I must say that's a record-setting comment. Is it possible to "homebrew" a Stirling cooler (with a reasonable amount of performance)? Half the reason behind this question is that my want to build and tinker has stirred up again and I'd get a kick out of the challenge. Also, what kind of considerations would I need to make for a Stirling cycle-based cooler? I'm somewhat familiar with the thermo theory, but not in any analytic regard.

Comment: Stirling machines do not LOOK that hard but the number of amateur ones that gain success wit any sort of sensible power levels re surprisingly small. One approach which I want to to try (may have to be next lifetime) is a "Gifford McMahon" machine (no known relationship. This uses a Carnot (Stirling) cycle but uses sinoker mechanicals. At one stage and maybe now the majority of cryogenic coolers )(not counting Joule Thomson) were GM machines. You need a displacer and cold end as before and regenerator. Pressure cycling uses an external pressure source (air compressor etc) and two valves.

Comment: ... 1. Displacer into cold end. 2. Open inlet valve. system pressurises.
3. Close inlet valve. Move displacer out of cold end. 4. Open exhaust valve. Pressure drops. Cold end cools. 5. Close exhaust valve. 
Repeat from 1. | GM machines may cycle at 5 to 10 cycles / second but are usually somewhat slower. In your case the "cold finger" can be in against the bottle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two wattage ratings for a peltier plates. One is the power consumed, the other is the heat transported across the chip **when there is a temperature difference of zero**. An important note is that the amount of heat transported across the plate is dependent on the temperature difference across the plate.

[image: Peltier graph]

Image courtesy of:
http://www.heatsink-guide.com/peltier.htm

Using the graph above as an example, if the hot side of the peltier plate is not attached to a heat sink then it will quickly heat up to 70 degrees hotter than the beverage unit and heat will stop flowing outward. At that point if this plate was 10% efficient it would still be producing out about 400W of heat. That heat would be produced on the hot side of the chip* but that means that without a heat sink of some sort the hot side would quickly become even hotter than 70 degrees above the beverage unit and heat would start to flow back into the beverage unit, heating it rather than cooling it.

Thus the heat sinks on your beverage "cooling" unit will be very, very important to how well your system cools (or heats) your beverage, and without any information on them my guess is that your system will heat your beverage.

*The heat is actually produced throughout the chip but it gets transferred out along with the other heat and the graph is compensated to account for this extra heat transfer, and only show the heat transferred away from the cool side.

Comment: Ah, so the overall system would be only as good as the ability to remove heat from the Peltiers. That makes perfect sense.